# Check whether PropertyInfo.SetValue will throw an ArgumentException

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I have inherited some code that tries to set a property:

```
object target = ...    // some instance on which we want to set a property
object value = ...     // some value - in this case, a string
var propertyInfo = ... // some property of target - in this case, not a string

try
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    // We go off and look for our own way of converting between
    // the type of value and the type of the property.
}
```

In current usage the exception is caught and thrown a lot, so I would like to make a check first:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
{
    // Try/catch as above
}
else
{
    // Do the manual conversion as if the exception had been thrown.
}
```

This runs much faster. However, my one concern is that `IsAssignableFrom` could return `false` for some pair of types where `SetValue` would in fact *succeed*. (This would cause us to look for the manual conversion when we don't need to, and possibly fail to set a value altogether.)

The spec for `SetValue` says

> *value* cannot be converted to the type of PropertyType

which is not exactly the same as assignability.

(If `IsAssignableFrom` returns `true` in cases where `SetValue` fails, that's fine - the manual conversion will still happen.)

Can someone confirm for me whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Please give an actual example where this happens. Presumably you have one, so it should be really easy to give a short but complete example which logs `IsAssignableFrom` and successfully calls `SetValue`. (This *may* only be an issue with primitives, which could be reasonably easily detected...)

Comment: @Jon The case I see failing a lot is trying to assign a `string` to a property of a custom type that is not assignable from `string` (but for which we have a custom converter). However, this code could be setting any type to any other type and I don't want to break it, so I'm interested in the general case.

Comment: Well I'm surprised that `SetValue` would call a custom converter - but again, a complete example would make that clear.

Comment: @Jon `SetValue` doesn't call the converter. We go and look for one if `SetValue` fails. I don't really think it's important what we do if it fails - I just need to know whether there are cases it disagrees with `IsAssignableFrom`.

Comment: What's important is that you're claiming `SetValue` would succeed when called with a type which cannot be converted to the property type. That seems unusual to me, so I've asked for an example. I'm not sure why you're reluctant to provide such an example. (It's not clear what you mean by "This would cause us to look for a TypeConverter" - what would? Where is that code? I would expect SetValue to fail and *then* you can look for a type converter...)

Comment: @Jon I'm not claiming it will succeed, I'm asking whether it's possible for it to.

Comment: Yes you are: "However, my one concern is that IsAssignableFrom could return false for some pair of types where SetValue **would in fact succeed**." Does `SetValue` succeed or not in this odd case?

Comment: @Jon That's... a turn of phrase. My one concern is that could do that. I am concerned that it is possible.

Comment: Ah. I see... so this is currently *purely* hypothetical, and you're just asking what kinds of conversion *are* supported by `SetValue`? I don't think you need to worry except *possibly* for primitive types - I would check what happens if you have a `long` property and an `int` value, for example. But other than that, I think you're fine.

Comment: @Jon Yup, pretty much. I'll push some primitive types through it and see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, a value of type `short` is assignable to a property of type `int` through reflection, although `typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(short))` returns `false`.

Looking at the stacktrace of the `ArgumentException`:

```
  at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
  at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
  at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value)
  at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...
```

The exception is thrown in `RuntimeType.TryChangeType`. Looking at the source in mscorlib:

```
// System.RuntimeType
[SecurityCritical]
private object TryChangeType(object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, bool needsSpecialCast)
{
    ...
    if (this.IsInstanceOfType(value))
    {
      return value;
    }
    ...
      if (RuntimeType.CanValueSpecialCast(valueType, this))
      {
    ...
  }
  throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_ObjObjEx"), value.GetType(), this));
}
```

Unfortunately there are many internal functions called to determine if an `ArgumentException` should be thrown. I suspect that the conversion of primitives are handled somewhere around this function:

```
// System.RuntimeType
[SecurityCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern bool CanValueSpecialCast(RuntimeType valueType, RuntimeType targetType);
```

There is some interesting code in `System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(object, Binder, CultureInfo, BindingFlags)` as well:

```
bool flag = base.IsPointer || this.IsEnum || base.IsPrimitive;
if (flag)
{
  ...
  if (RuntimeType.CanValueSpecialCast(valueType, this))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

So it looks like pointer, enum and primitive types are handled in a different way. I discourage you to try to copy that logic. It might be easier to just use `IsAssignableFrom`, and handle integral types separately. Handling pointer, enum and primitive type arguments looks very complicated, I would just fallback to `try-catch` there. However, you can cache if an argument error happened so subsequent calls on the same method with same parameter types might be somewhat faster.

Comment: Thanks, hege. I'd just found the `long`/`int` example myself but you've done much better at finding where and what the logic is than I have, and the caching idea is great - I'll probably end up going down that route.